# How to determine local symmetry of graph nodes in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am using NetworkX to generate undirected graphs like the one shown in the picture below. The colors represent the equality of graph nodes, i.e., nodes of the same color are of the same type. The colors are stored as an attribute of each node. Now, I wish to determine all possible symmetry equivalent groups of nodes in the graph using NetworkX. By symmetry equivalent, I mean that switching those nodes will provide an identical graph (not just isomorphic, but identical).

[image: graph picture]

For example, in the above graph, nodes 5 and 6 are interchangeable by symmetry. Thus, `{5:6}` is a local symmetry mapping. Additionally, nodes 2, 5, 6 and nodes 3, 7, 8 are also identical due to symmetry. Therefore, `{2:3, 5:7, 6:8}` would also be a valid symmetry mapping. There would be many other valid symmetry mappings.

**Is there a function in NetworkX that I can use to identify these symmetry mappings (and possibly generate new graphs by permuting those node indices)?** A google search led me to [this](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.ISMAGS.analyze_symmetry.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.ISMAGS.analyze_symmetry) page, but there is no documentation on how to use this function, and it is not even clear to me if the function does what I am trying to accomplish or is it something else entirely. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's an idea for efficiently locating symmetries. Visit each node 5 .. 10, shoot a spanning tree through the graph rooted at that node, and serialize it. For example, from node 10 write a line 10 - 1;  also a line 10 - 1 - 9; 10 - 1 - 3; 10 - 1 - 3 - 8, and so on. But rather than writing integer IDs of neighbors, just write the colors, so we have the root ID in column 1 followed by a list of one or more colors in column 2. Sort by column 2, look for entries with identical column 2 value, and you'll have a bunch of candidate symmetries to test. This is only a start, as cycles are trouble.

Comment: @J_H Yes I thought about going one-by-one through nodes, but I need to deal with cycles as well. Full disclosure, these graphs are molecular connectivity graphs, so I absolutely need to be able to work with cycles (like benzene for example). I thought networkx would have some useful feature.

Comment: The "find MST, then sort paths to find identical prefixes" approach has the advantage of being scalable, but the disadvantage of being cycle oblivious, since MST will make an arbitrary choice of which cycle edges to skip. Since cycles matter, we could use the NetworkX [simple_cycle](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/cycles.html) enumeration and either (1.) derive a related graph where each cycle is a single supernode, or (2.) track the cycle edges used by MST so far, deliberately delete one, and ask MST to re-solve that related problem, going the other way round.